# Actualizar icono rojo badge después de una notificación remota Firebase con swift 3

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, firebase, push-notification

Le comento mi duda, tengo una aplicación en SWIFT 3 conectada con Firebase para las notificaciones ya he dado permisos y creado los certificados APNS, y funciona perfecto la notificación llega a los dispositivos físicos.

¿Lo que quisiera saber es como puedo actualizar la burbujita roja o badge despues de una notificación?

[image: hola]

Se que para asignar un numero al badge es de la siguiente manera.

```
let application = UIApplication.shared
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2
```

Estuve investigando un poco y encontré hacerlo de forma local pero de forma remota es muy diferente o como se hace?

He añadido el anterior código en las siguientes funciones esperando que lograse ejecutarse después de recibir las notificaciones por firebase sin exito del AppDelegate.swift

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)

private func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)
```

Cual es la función que se ejecuta después de recibir una notificación desde Firebase?.

También he leído que el badge se puede enviar mediante un parámetro en firebase, yo lo hago mediante ruby de la siguiente forma.

```
fcm = FCM.new(key)

array = {notification: {body: message}, priority: "high", content_available: true, badge: 24}

response = fcm.send_to_topic("tema_prueba", array)
```

Me llega la notificación al dispositivo físico pero no se actualiza el badge.

Que estoy haciendo mal? Es correcto hacerlo por parámetro desde firebase? pero hay que añadir algo mas en el código en AppDelegate o se hace de otra forma?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días.

Si configuras bien el badge en el servidor de notificaciones debe actualizarse solo.
El caso es que en realidad debe ser el dispositivo del usuario el que auto actualice el badget en la mayoría de casos.

A no ser que el servidor sepa en todo momento el estado de la app. Pero ti tu app tiene funcionamiento offline debes controlar el badget desde el dispositivo.

Te dejo aquí un JSON de una notificación por si te puede ayudar en algo a encontrar tu problema.

```
{
 "aps":{
        "alert":"Testing.. (0)",
        "badge":1,
        "sound":"default"
       }
}
```

Comment: Gracias pero esto no lo resuelve, es decir mando la notificación con esos parametros y no actualiza el badge

Answer (score 0):

Si la aplicación recibe correctamente el badge pero no lo utiliza es probable que no lo hayas incluido en los permisos o no lo hayas registrado

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (correcto, error) in
        if correcto{
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

func registerForPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
```